# Composition of non-continuous functions continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Give an example of two functions $f: (0,2) \to (0,2)$ and $g :(0,2) \to \Bbb R$ that are not continuous, but the composition $g \circ f$ is.

I started to think about this and graph some functions and I wondered is there an easy way to visualize the composition of two functions? Say I take $$g(x)=\begin{cases}x & x \ne 1\\
1/2& x = 1 \end{cases}$$ this is just a straight line through the origin with the value $1$ removed and replaced with $1/2$. Now what I thought I could do now is to define a non-continuous function $f$ such that $f$ never outputs $1$ since that is the point of discontinuity for $g$. So if I take something like $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \ne 1\\
1/2 & x= 1 \end{cases}$$

this is never $1$, but the composition will then be $$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}0 & x \ne 1\\
1/2 & x = 1 \end{cases}=f(x)$$ which is not continuous.

So making sure that $f$ never outputs $1$ is not sufficient to make $g \circ f$ continuous. What other things I need to check in order to make the composition continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example: for fixed $0<\alpha,\beta<2$ with $\alpha\neq \beta$, let
$$\begin{split}
f(x)&:=\begin{cases}
\alpha, & x \in (0,1),\\
\beta, & x \in [1,2),
\end{cases} \qquad \text{and} \\[0.8em] g(x) &:= \begin{cases}
1, & x \in \{\alpha,\beta\},\\
0, & \text{elsewhere in }(0,2).
\end{cases}
\end{split}$$
Then $f,g$ are not continuous, but $g\circ f$ is identically $1$ on $(0,2)$.

The idea behind this example is that the "simplest" continuous functions are constants, and the "simplest" discontinuous functions are those that are constant almost everywhere apart from a single jump. So we take $f$ to be of the latter kind, and we seek $g$ so that $g\circ f$ is of the former kind.